# Getting Empty Response body with Retrofit2--> Unable to populate data

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

This is my "Client.java" code for the movie app, where I have passed the base URL for the API.

```
public static Retrofit getClient(){
      if (retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
```

Below is the code for the "Service.java", where I am using @GET method:

```
@GET("movie/popular?api_key=")
Call<MoviesResponse> getPopularMovies(@Query("f48e0ffb5@@@@@@@@11f966fd71e8") String apikey) ;

@GET("movie/top_rated?api_key=")
Call<MoviesResponse> getTopRatedMovies(@Query("f48e0@@@@@@@@d1c11f966fd71e8") String apikey) ;
}
```

Below is the code for getting the response from the server and loading the JSON. But I am unable to build up the successful response from the server:

```
private void loadJSON(){

    Client Client = new Client();

    Service service = Client.getClient().create(Service.class) ;

    Call<MoviesResponse> call =service.getPopularMovies(API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Response<MoviesResponse> response) {
            if(response.code()==200) {
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();

                Collections.sort(movies, Movie.BY_NAME_ALPHABETICAL);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), movies));
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            }else
            {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR_FETCHING_DATA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

The Gradle script:

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
```

Comment: The code seems incomplete, potentially. And what does "unable to" mean? Give a proper description of what actually happens, and compare with what you wanted/expected to happen.

Comment: Can you check what you are getting in the response? try to replace Call<MoviesResponse> with Call<JsonObject>. 
By this you will get to know the json.

Comment: It should fetch data from moviedb api and populate on screen. But nothing is getting displayed and showing the toast message: "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR_FETCHING_DATA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()"

Comment: can you post your expected endpoint for ws here, I mean your url whıch has data